# Fetching Market Data from Bloomberg API

Tags: java, api, bloomberg

I am working on a requirement in my firm to fetch Market Data from Bloomberg for Analytics.
I tried to implement it after reading the blpapi developer's guide in Java.
But i was getting "could not start the session" error.

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.setServerHost("localhost");       
sessionOptions.setServerPort(8194); 
Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);
 if (!session.start()) 
 {
     System.out.println("Could not start session.");
     System.exit(1);
 }
```

Then i searched and got to know that i need to have a Bloomberg Terminal installed and running on my system.
After installing Bloomberg Terminal now its asking for an access key.
Can anyone please tell me  what all the steps i need to follow before running my application??

Comment: You need to have a valid Bloomberg subscription (or more likely, in your case, a programmer license, which is generally less expensive). You need to ask Bloomberg or whoever at your firm who is in contact with them.

Comment: Thanks for replying..It means fetching data from Bloomberg is not free ? Also if you could tell me how to fetch data from B-Pipe.What all will be needed in case of B-Pipe?

Comment: No it's not free. I don't know b pipe...

Comment: Thanks alot assylias.

Comment: The same api is used to fetch data via B-Pipe, however, you will need to implement additional code for authentication and authorization. You will need to contact Bloomberg sales reps to learn more about B-Pipe requirements.

Comment: From where did you got `com.bloomberglp.blapi` dependency?